# Automate slappasswd

Tags: centos, slappasswd

I want to automate slappasswd, but the following does not work:

```
[root@controller ~]# echo -e "vagrant\nvagrant\n" | slappasswd
New password:
```

while it works to automate passwd:

```
[root@controller ~]# echo -e "vagrant\nvagrant\n" | passwd vagrant
Changing password for user vagrant.
New password: BAD PASSWORD: The password is shorter than 8 characters
Retype new password: passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

**Questions**

1. Why does this method not work to automate slappasswd?
2. How to automate slappasswd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/slappasswd) you can
provide the password as an argument:

```
slappasswd -s vagrant
```

Otherwise slappasswd reads from the tty and not stdin to get a new
password. You can use something like `expect` to talk to it in this case.

Comment: Be careful when writing passwords as a command argument. Anyone on the system can use ps to see your command line arguments, and the command gets stored in your shell history fole

Comment: @atk Perhaps you could post a safer alternative

Comment: @185140777 heredoc and disabling command history usually solves it. I don't have a system handy to test, and encourage others to post such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

(An alternative to [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211155/119298)).
Programs that expect user interaction on /dev/tty rather than just reading
stdin can be handled with the **expect** command, which uses the tcl
language. For example, assuming you have expect in /usr/bin/expect, create
a file `setuserpw` holding this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
expect_user -re "(\[^ \]+) (\[^ \]+)\n"
set user $expect_out(1,string)
set pw   $expect_out(2,string)
spawn passwd $user
expect "password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect eof
```

and dont forget to make it executable

```
chmod +x ./setuserpw
```

The script reads stdin for two words on a line, and sets variables `user`
and `pw` to these. It then runs (spawn) the `passwd` program for the user,
connecting via a pseudo tty (see `man pty`). It reads its output for a
prompt matching "password:". It then sends the password to the program, and
does the same again (assuming the program asks you for the password twice).
For example:

```
./setuserpw <<!
user1 passwd1
!
```

In your case, replace `passwd` by `slappasswd`, and verify the prompts you
get correspond to those in this example.